# SQL - Unqiue results based on criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Making a dealer locator where people search for a dealer near them. I want it to work in such a way that if a dealer has multiple branches near the person, only the closest branch shows. So the "name" field should be unique in the results with the result shown having the least distance to the person searching versus other rows that have the same "name" field. I also want only the closest 5 dealers shown ordered by their dealer level, or medal. Right now I have the following:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT
name, address, contact, image, medal, phone, email, website, lat, lng,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM dealers
HAVING distance < 60
ORDER BY medal, distance
LIMIT 0 , 5",
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

From what I've read, it sounds like I need to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY distance) AS num
FROM dealers)a
WHERE a.num = 1
```

Or something like that, but I can't get it to work right. Any insights on how I can get this to function would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support window functions such as row_number.

Comment: Don't use `sprintf` for parameterized queries, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).  It's safer and makes code more maintainable.

Comment: [dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/mysql-and-window-functions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/mysql-and-window-functions) might help.

Comment: You're using a database API that has been deprecated for 5 years, and is not even present in the current version of PHP. Alternatives like PDO have been available for over a decade. Use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Solution was:

```
        SELECT name, address, contact, image, medal, phone, email, website, lat, lng, 
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM dealers 
    WHERE (name,
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) )
        IN 
        (SELECT name, distance 
            FROM (SELECT name,
            MIN( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
            FROM dealers 
            WHERE (3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) < 90
            GROUP BY name) 
        t) 

    ORDER BY medal, distance 
    LIMIT 0, 5",

    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat)
```

Thank you Thorsten Kettner, for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Get the minimum distance per dealer and of these take the first five. Then select again from the table in order to get complete records, but take only those records already identified by dealer and distance.

A `WITH` clause would be helpful, but MySQL doesn't support it. Well, ...

```
SELECT
  name, address, contact, image, medal, phone, email, website, lat, lng,
  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM dealers
WHERE (name, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )) IN
(
  SELECT
    name, min( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
  FROM dealers
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING distance < 60
  ORDER BY distance
  LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY distance, medal;
```

Comment: Great idea! That should work. Tried to get it to work for awhile but I can't, returns no results, reason being is because I have very little idea of what I am doing, databases don't like me. I'll work on it.